# Styling Active Links Within Wordpress

Tags: menus, css

I wish to style the active link (ie. when home page is selected that the home page link be a different colour)

```
.current-menu-item a { color: #36c; }
```

My test site is : www.milknhny.co.uk/ShopTest

I placed this in the CSS as i believe this was the class that i wished to change, however it does not appear to have worked.

Could i please ask where i have gone wrong on this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set `#menuwrap ul li.current-menu-item a` to the color and style you want.

The Problem is actually a CSS issue - because the CSS is more specific if an ID of an element is defined (like in your `#menuwrap ul li a`), so the above definition is even more specific and is used instead of the current one.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code for CSS:

```
#menuwrap ul li.current-menu-item a{ color: #36c; }
```

I would also suggest you to use Opera's Dragonfly, FireFoxe's Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to debug your CSS, JS and other things...